# Python - Trouble pulling data from multiple excel files in folder

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a script that will open/look through every excel workbook inside a folder, pull specific values from each of those workbooks, and then paste those values into a new csv.

My script (see below), and all 49 workbooks are located in the following path: C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\Excel Test.

```
import pandas
import os

info_headers = ['Production Name', 'Data size (GBs)', 'Billable Data size (GBs)']
info = []

files = [file for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\user.name\\Desktop\\Excel Test')]
for file in files:
    df = pandas.read_excel(file)
    size = df['Unnamed: 2'].loc[df['QC Checklist'] == 'Data Size (GB):'].values[0]
    name = df['Unnamed: 2'].loc[df['QC Checklist'] == 'Production Volume Name'].values[0]
    bill_size = df['Unnamed: 2'].loc[df['QC Checklist'] == 'Billable Data Size (GB):'].values[0]
    info.append([name, size, bill_size])

output = pandas.DataFrame(info, columns=info_headers)
output.to_csv('C:\\Users\\user.name\\Excel Test')  # This will output a csv in your current directory
```

I receive the following error when trying to run this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/Excel Test/exceltest.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pandas.read_excel(file)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 188, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 350, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 653, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 424, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'import p'
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of problems. It may be trying to open non-excel files in the directory. After your os.listdir() call, try to filter for excel files only.

Or your excel file may be formatted incorrectly.